# How to print call responce in Log message into json format

Tags: android, retrofit2, android-json, gson

I Used retrofit 2.0 for server calls becaue consuming json and sending json. I am getting return responce with status code. but, my values are not inserted into server. i think my json data wrong. but, how can I print our client side json means Callrespose in Log.d(). I tried but no solution. 
Main.java :

```
 ApiConfig getResponse = AppConfig.getRetrofit().create(ApiConfig.class);
        UserDTO userDTO=new UserDTO();
        userDTO.setUserid(userId);
        userDTO.setFile(file);
        userDTO.setUsers(adapter.usersList);

       Call<UserDTO> response = getResponse.ShareFiles(userDTO);

        Log.d("Shared Files : ",userDTO.toString());

        response.enqueue(new Callback<UserDTO>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<UserDTO> call, Response<UserDTO> response) {
                Log.d("Shared Friends Responce call : ", String.valueOf(call.isExecuted())+"\n"+call.toString()+"\n"+call.clone());

                Log.d("Shared Friends Responce : ",response.message()+" "+response.code());

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<UserDTO> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("Shared Friends Error : ",t.getMessage());
            }
        });
```

API Config:

```
public class AppConfig {
private static String BASE_URL = "http://104.236.67.117:8000/";
    static Retrofit getRetrofit() {
        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(AppConfig.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the solution

**Step 1:**
   OK HTTP Add dependencies in Build.gradle

```
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
```

**Step 2:** In Appconfig

```
 HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();  
    logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();   
    httpClient.addInterceptor(logging); // this is for log interceptor
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()  
    .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .client(httpClient.build())
    .build();
```

Comment: May I use like this : logging.d("Main activity", response); where response is call<Serverresponse>response.

Comment: This is the way to print of log level body.Here you will get the response easy way to find the exception or anything

Comment: it help full. you saved my time. thank you @Rajasekhar Reddy